# ngFor it does not return anything

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a list that comes from a service, and in the component I'm trying to load it into a select-option, but it does not get me anything. The service method is fine because I've checked it, does anyone see the error?

This is the component:

```
public listaAnyos: number;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAnyos(this.listaAnyos);
  }
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="anio" [(ngModel)]="anyoSeleccionado" (change)="getControlEstadoMes($event.target.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let anyos of listaAnyos"></option>  
</select>
```

Comment: `<option *ngFor="let anyos of listaAnyos">{{anyos}}</option>`

Comment: You have to output the value from the *ngFor e.g. `<option *ngFor="let anyos of listaAnyos">{{anyos}}</option>`

Comment: You define `listaAnyos` as a number, but it should be an array. Also, where do you assign something to `listaAnyos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong.

Component

```
public listaAnyos: number[];

ngOnInit() {
   this.listaAnyos = this.service.getAnyos(); // Assuming that getAnyos() returns array of number(Anyos).
}
```

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" id="anio" [(ngModel)]="anyoSeleccionado" (change)="getControlEstadoMes($event.target.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let anyos of listaAnyos">{{anyos}}</option>  
</select>
```